# How to remove duplicated data in multiple parallel arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to remove certain array elements of the same exact order in swift which have multiple identical values
ie.

assume now I have 3 arrays

```
array1 = [a,b,c,d,d,c,d]
array2 = [1,2,3,4,4,3,4]
array3 = [aa,bb,cc,dd,dd,cc,dd]
```

The problem is: I need to remove from the array the elements which have all 3 duplicated values altogether

Which means, I need to get rid of elements with index: [4], [5], [6] from arrays 1, 2 and 3.

ps. 3 arrays have to be in separated arrays and can't rearrange its order since they have some critical information related to each other

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is different from the duplicate, in that it must deal with multiple parallel arrays, instead of a single array. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Does your array elements are all equatable? Btw you should show your attempt to solve your problem and the issues you are facing

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, they were appended and generated at the same time, and their elements number is exactly the same

Comment: I mean the elements are only strings and numbers or they have custom structures or classes?

Comment: @LeoDabus sorry my bad. Well, they are just simple string and Int.

Comment: Would it change the desired result if I replaced the last `"dd"` of `array3` with `"dx"`?

Comment: Seems like a more appropriate data structure is to create struct/class/tuple of the array1/2/3 attributes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, since I'm dealing with duplicated array where it automatically generated. So, It wouldn't be possible to have such a different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are `Equatable` (given that their elements are `Equatable`) up to arity 6, which we could make use of here to zip the three arrays into a sequence of 3-tuples, identifying repeated 3-tuple elements, and removing the indices associated with these tuples from the original three arrays. Tuples are not, however, `Hashable`, so instead of using 3-tuples we could fall back on a utility `Hashable` type storing the three values (that the 3-tuple did type anonymously).

Utility type:

```
struct ZippedElement: Hashable {
    let a: String
    let b: Int
    let c: String

    init(_ a: String, _ b: Int, _ c: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    }

    // Use a very simple common hashValue calculation, simply
    // falling back on the hashValue of the Int member.
    var hashValue: Int { return b.hashValue }

    static func ==(lhs: ZippedElement, rhs: ZippedElement) -> Bool {
        return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b && lhs.c == rhs.c
    }
}
```

Which allows us to perform the filtering/mutating operations on `array1` through `array3` as follows:

```
var seen = Set<ZippedElement>()
zip(zip(array1, array2), array3)
    .map { ZippedElement($0.0, $0.1, $1) }
    .enumerated().filter { !seen.insert($1).inserted }
    .map { $0.offset }.reversed()
    .forEach {
        array1.remove(at: $0)
        array2.remove(at: $0)
        array3.remove(at: $0)
    }
```

With, as a result, the last three elements being removed in each array:

```
print(array1) // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
print(array2) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(array3) // ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
```

---

Your example data setup doesn't pose many challenges for the different solutions here, however, so @dasblinkenlight asks a good question:

> Would it change the desired result if I replaced the last `"dd"` of `array3` with `"dx"`?

In this case, I believe most of us assume that the 7th element in all the original arrays should be kept, as the "vertical" zip combination over all three arrays, for the 7th element (/column), is unique.

Applying the same approach as above for such a modified example:

```
var array1 = ["a",  "b",  "c",  "d",  "d",  "c",  "d"]
var array2 = [ 1,    2,    3,    4,    4,    3,    4]
var array3 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "dd", "cc", "dx"]
                                               /*  ^^ obs */

var seen = Set<ZippedElement>()
zip(zip(array1, array2), array3)
    .map { ZippedElement($0.0, $0.1, $1) }
    .enumerated().filter { !seen.insert($1).inserted }
    .map { $0.offset }.reversed()
    .forEach {
        print($0)
        array1.remove(at: $0)
        array2.remove(at: $0)
        array3.remove(at: $0)
    }

print(array1) // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "d"]
print(array2) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
print(array3) // ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dx"]
                                  /* ^^ ok */
```

---

Another comment to your question is asked by @SteveKuo, stating what is on probably on most of our minds (in excess of a somewhat fun algorithmic exercise) for all questions such as this one (index-tracking separate arrays ...):

> Seems like a more appropriate data structure is to create struct/class/tuple of the array1/2/3 attributes.

And I believe this is the core answer you should take with you here, so even if you explicitly state

> ... ps. 3 arrays have to be in separated arrays

You probably want a single array of a custom type instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var array1 = ["a","b","c","d","d","c","d"]
var array2 = [1,2,3,4,4,3,4]
var array3 = ["aa","bb","cc","dd","dd","cc","dd"]
var set: Set<Int> = []   // you can use a set to check the duplicated elements

for index in array2.indices.reversed() { // reversed is necessary to remove your elements
    if !set.insert(array2[index]).inserted {
        array1.remove(at: index)
        array2.remove(at: index)
        array3.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

---

```
array1  // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
array2  // [1, 2, 3, 4]
array3  // ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
```

Comment: I think you ignored the part of the requirement where OP says " I need to remove from the array the elements which have all 3 duplicated values altogether," because your `seen` array pays attention only to `array1`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it was done in purpose considering that the duplicated elements are always positioned in the same index. Thats how I interpreted the question and OP example supports it. Let's see what he says about it.

Comment: I suspect OP wasn't careful creating his example. [I asked him a question about it, let's see what he says.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817377/how-to-remove-duplicated-data-in-multiple-parallel-arrays/46817821?noredirect=1#comment80583850_46817377)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the array into a set (which will inherently not contain duplicates), and then transfer it back to an array.

e.g.

```
var array2: [Int] = [1,2,3,4,4,3,4]
let set2 = Set<Int>(array2)
array2 = Array(set2).sorted()
```

If you need to to do set logic against other arrays as well, you can do something like `set2.subtract(otherSequence)`.

Comment: This will result in an unordered array. Nothing guarantees that the input will be always sorted()

Comment: @LeoDabus I added a sort function, in case doing so wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions cover a working approach but all do so in O(n^2) time due to iterating through the array and calling `remove(at:)` repeatedly which is itself an O(n) operation.

Assuming all 3 arrays have duplicates in the same spots, here is a functional O(n) approach which instead uses swapping and then just trims the array once at the end. Not sure how much performance matters but this should run significantly quicker on larger datasets.

```
var array1 = ["a","b","c","d","d","c","d"]
var array2 = [1,2,3,4,4,3,4]
var array3 = ["aa","bb","cc","dd","dd","cc","dd"]

var set: Set<Int> = []

var lastIndex = 0
for index in array2.indices
{
    if set.insert(array2[index]).inserted
    {
        array1.swapAt(index, lastIndex)
        array2.swapAt(index, lastIndex)
        array3.swapAt(index, lastIndex)
        lastIndex += 1
    }
}

let numToRemove = array1.count - lastIndex
array1.removeLast(numToRemove)
array2.removeLast(numToRemove)
array3.removeLast(numToRemove)
```